# MySQL advise on building a database with connected tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to build a database which holds information about users in a table:

```
User
 -username (primary key)
 -first_name
 -second_name
 -Image
```

In this database there will be another table like so:

```
Image
 -name (primary key)
 -file_name
```

## What I want to achieve

I want each user to have Image as one of its fields. I understand to do this I have to connect the tables.

## What I know so far

Firstly I should define the tables as InnoDB, then using phpmyadmin click on relationView.

## The Question

How do I achieve the relationship I described above using phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user have only one image it is one to one relationship. Everything can do with a one table.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userFirstName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  userSecondName VARCHAR(80),
  imageName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userId)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Multiple images have to one user, there is a one to many relationship. So you can create two tables and one lookup table.

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   userId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   userFirstName VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   userSecondName VARCHAR(80),
   imageName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (userId)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE images (
   imageId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   imageName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (imageId)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Lookup table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_image ( 
   userId INT UNSIGNED,
   imageId INT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put a column on table `Image` that will be reference on the table `User`, if for intance, a user can have multiple images. ex,

**User**

- username (*primary key*)
- first_name
- second_name

**Image**

- name (*primary key*)
- file_name
- userName (*Foreign Key*)

---

translated into DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `User`
(
    userName VARCHAR(15),
    first_name VARCHAR(15),
    second_name VARCHAR(15),
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (userName),
    CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (first_name, last_name)
);

CREATE TABLE `Image`
(
    name VARCHAR(15),
    file_name VARCHAR(75),
    userName VARCHAR(15)
    CONSTRAINT tb_pk PRIMARY KEY (name),
    CONSTRAINT tb_fk FOREIGN KEY (userName) REFERENCES `User`(userName)
);
```

Comment: What if the images table was not just used for users?  But could also be other images for other purposes.

Comment: @Svip actually there are any other design other than that. I was only assuming that table `images` holds the images for every `user`. In you case, I'll be making 3 tables for it.